# What is the proper way to indicate which data source to inject into my DAOs in a multi-module multi-datasource project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multi-module, multi-database

I have a project split into 3 modules (so far) - core (Model 1), user-management (model 2) and web (View and Controller). My project structure (simplified to only relevant classes for the sake of getting to the point) is as follows:

```
Project  
|-- core  
|  |-- src.main.java.com.romco.example  
|  |  |-- config.CoreDataSourceConfiguration  
|  |  |-- persistence.daoimpl.SomeCoreDaoImpl  
|-- user-management  
|  |-- src.main.kotlin.com.romco.example  
|  |  |-- config.UserManagementConfiguration  
|  |  |-- persistence.daoimpl.SomeUserManagementDaoImpl  
|-- web  
| // not important right now
```

My classes are as follows (while debugging my previous issue, I had to move some value initialization directly to code instead of using application.properties, as noted by the TODO, so please ignore it for the sake of the problem at hand)

- CoreDataSourceConfiguration:

```
    @Configuration
    public class CoreDataSourceConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DataSourceProperties coreDataSourceProperties() {
            return new DataSourceProperties();
        }
    
        //TODO values should be retrieved from application.properties
    
        @Bean(name = "coreDataSource")
        @Primary
        public DataSource coreDataSource() {
            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSourceBuilder.url("...");
            dataSourceBuilder.username("...");
            dataSourceBuilder.password("...");
            return dataSourceBuilder.build();
        }
    
        @Bean(name = "coreTransactionManager")
        @Autowired
        DataSourceTransactionManager coreTransactionManager(@Qualifier("coreDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        }
    }
```

- SomeCoreDaoImpl:

```
    @Repository
    public class SomeCoreDaoImpl implements SomeCoreDao {
        
        // some constants here
    
        private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
        
        @Autowired
        @Override
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
            namedParameterJdbcTemplate = NamedParameterJdbcTemplateHolder.get(dataSource);
        }
    
        // DB code here - create, update, etc.
        
    }
```

- UserManagementConfiguration:

```
    @Configuration
    open class UserManagementDataSourceConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        open fun userManagementDataSourceProperties(): DataSourceProperties {
            return DataSourceProperties()
        }
    
        @Bean(name = ["userManagementDataSource"])
        open fun userManagementDataSource(): DataSource {
            val dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create()
            dataSourceBuilder
                    .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                    .url("...")
                    .username("...")
                    .password("...")
            return dataSourceBuilder.build()
        }
    
        @Bean(name = ["userManagementTransactionManager"])
        @Autowired
        open fun userManagementTransactionManager(@Qualifier("userManagementDataSource") dataSource: DataSource): DataSourceTransactionManager {
            return DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource)
        }
      }
```

- SomeUserManagementDaoImpl:

```
    @Repository
    open class SomeUserManagementDaoImpl: SomeUserManagementDao{
    
        // constants are here
    
        private lateinit var namedParameterJdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
    
        @Autowired
        fun setDataSource(@Qualifier("userManagementDataSource") dataSource: DataSource) {
            namedParameterJdbcTemplate = NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource)
        }
    
        // DB code here
    
    }
```

As you can see, the way I made it work is by specifying which bean to use in the autowired setDataSource method inside my SomeUserManagementDaoImpl class.

I would obviously prefer to avoid having to do this in every daoImpl class, and while I can think of extracting this to a single class, it doesn't seem like that's the "spring" intended solution.

Now (again, obviously) - The data sources are module-specific, and initially, I even assumed spring would somehow figure it out under the hood and, instead of using the @Primary datasource, would use the one defined in a given module (unless that module had none, in which case I assumed it would fall back to the @Primary one).
However, that was not the case, and I'm left wondering if there is some way to tell spring to use a given data source configuration across that entire module...

I've been looking at many similiar threads and guides that deal with multi-datasource projects, but I actually never found the answer. In fact, the guides which I consulted when I was implementing my multi-datasource solution never mentioned this at all (unless I missed it), eg.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

It is also entirely possible that I'm doing something else terribly wrong, and that is the root cause, in which case, please, also help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case anyone stumbles upon the same problem, here's how I solved it so far. I might come up with a more elegant solution in the future, or more likely, find an issue with this one, but for now it seems to be working (haven't done much testing yet though):

In the user-management module (the one NOT using the @Primary datasource), I created the following abstract class, extracting the dataSource injection (with the qualifier specifying the datasource) to one place:

```
    abstract class WithDataSource {
    
        protected lateinit var namedParameterJdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
    
        @Autowired
        fun setDataSource(@Qualifier(USER_MANAGEMENT_DATA_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME) dataSource: DataSource) {
            namedParameterJdbcTemplate = NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource)
        }
    
    }
```

Each of my user-management DaoImpl classes then extends this class, and therefore implicitly implements the setDataSource() method of my GenericDao interface.

For completeness, the user-management module now looks like this (I included some previously omitted interfaces, but still left the "example" naming and omitted some specific utility code):

```
    Project  
    |-- core  
    |  |-- src.main.java.com.romco.example  
    |  |  |-- config.CoreDataSourceConfiguration  
    |  |  |-- persistence.daoimpl.SomeCoreDaoImpl  
    |-- user-management  
    |  |-- src.main.kotlin.com.romco.example  
    |  |  |-- config.UserManagementConfiguration  
    |  |  |-- persistence.dao.GenericDao  
    |  |  |-- persistence.daoimpl.SomeUserManagementDaoImpl  
    |  |  |-- persistence.util.DaoUtil.kt  
    |-- web  
    | // not important right now
```

- UserManagementConfiguration (added bean name as constant USER_MANAGEMENT_DATA_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME):

```
    @Configuration
    open class UserManagementDataSourceConfiguration {

        companion object {
            const val USER_MANAGEMENT_DATA_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME = "userManagementDataSource"
        }

        @Bean
        open fun userManagementDataSourceProperties(): DataSourceProperties {
            return DataSourceProperties()
        }
    
        @Bean(name = ["userManagementDataSource"])
        open fun userManagementDataSource(): DataSource {
            val dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create()
            dataSourceBuilder
                    .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                    .url("...")
                    .username("...")
                    .password("...")
            return dataSourceBuilder.build()
        }
    
        @Bean(name = ["userManagementTransactionManager"])
        @Autowired
        open fun userManagementTransactionManager(@Qualifier("userManagementDataSource") dataSource: DataSource): DataSourceTransactionManager {
            return DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource)
        }
      }
```

- GenericDao (wasn't mentioned in original quesiton, as it was not too relevant, including for completeness of solution):

```
    interface GenericDao<T> {
        fun setDataSource(dataSource: DataSource)
        // retrieves all
        fun retrieveAll(): Collection<T>
        // creates and returns id of the newly created record. In case of failure, returns -1.
        fun create(t: T): Long
        // updates by id, returns true if success.
        fun update(t: T): Boolean
        // deletes by id, returns true if success.
        fun delete(t: T): Boolean
        // performs cleanup, for example, might delete all test records (id < 0)
        fun cleanup()
    }
```

- SomeUserManagementDao (wasn't mentioned in original quesiton, as it was not too relevant, including for completeness of solution):

```
    interface SomeUserManagementDao: GenericDao<SomeUserManagementClass> {
        fun retrieveBySpecificValue(specificValue: String): SomeUserManagementClass?
    }
```

- SomeUserManagementDaoImpl (updated as mentioned in comment):

```
    @Repository
    open class SomeUserManagementDaoImpl: SomeUserManagementDao, WithDataSource() {
    
        // constants are here
    
        // namedParameterJdbcTemplate and setDataSource() are now inherited from the parent class - WithDataSource
    
        // DB code here
    
    }
```

- DaoUtil.kt (contains the originally mentioned abstract class along with some other, in this case omitted, utilities):

```
    abstract class WithDataSource {
    
        protected lateinit var namedParameterJdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
    
        @Autowired
        fun setDataSource(@Qualifier(USER_MANAGEMENT_DATA_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME) dataSource: DataSource) {
            namedParameterJdbcTemplate = NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource)
        }
    
    }
```